# Read data from GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, save

I have a general question :

If I got a GUI (e.g. metaTrader => online broker), is it possible to read data from this GUI using java?

My idea:

Using the java.awt.robot and do something like:

```
package java_robot;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class java_robot {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       try {
           // create class
           Robot robot = new Robot();

           // wait 1 sec
           robot.delay(1000);

           // move mouse to wanted area
           robot.mouseMove(x, y);
           }

           // mark an area, copy it and save in file..

       } catch (AWTException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Is this idea good, or do you know other solution´s to read data from a GUI? 
(working on mac)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Robot#createScreenCapture()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) method here.

```
Robot r = new Robot();

// Capture area
int width = ...
int height = ...
Rectangle area = new Rectangle(width, height);
BufferedImage image = r.createScreenCapture(area);

// Save to file
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("/screenshot.png"));
```

Alternatively, if metaTrader loads its data from internet, you can sniffe its traffic and determine how and where its data comes. Then you could try to mimic its internet calls and get the data yourself as long as it is not ciphered.

You could also build a proxy in Java and ask metaTrader to use this proxy. All data requested by metaTrader would go through your proxy. This can give you a chance to read the data... again as long as it is not ciphered.

The image below illustrates how things work. Alice plays the role of meaTrader. Bob is the source of data of metaTrader. Proxy is your Java app.

[image]

You can find a simple implementation of such a proxy here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/Asimpleproxyserver.htm.

References:

- [Proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server)

Comment: great idea´s, What do you mean by "ask metaTrader to use this proxy", i just need the port which metatrader use´s or?

Comment: @user3297073 When metaTrader , or any application, connects to Internet, it either does it directly or by using a proxy. Usually, the application permits throught its settings to configure a proxy. Once configured, the app forwards all its internet calls to the proxy. The proxy in return forwards the calls to the internet appropriately.

Comment: ok, but what u mean exactly with "ask metaTrader to use this proxy", are there any setting´s in metaTrader or is it about listening to a specific port?

Comment: i just want the proxy to get all data, which is sent to metatrader. so the proxy needs to listen to a port?

Comment: @user3297073 The proxy listen on a port. metaTrader will connect on this port. Then the proxy forwards calls, made by metaTrader, to the actual source of data of metaTrader. When the source replies, the proxy forwards back the data to metaTrader. Read this article for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server